# grep not showing result which read id from file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've two files named db_name.txt and id.txt

db_name.txt files :

```
111111  Steven
222222  Bob
333333  Marry
444444  July
555555  Venus
666666  Porter
777777  Guerson
888888  Yeti
999999  Piza
```

https://filedn.com/lErjiEcIItPyfm4zDdHlyIz/db_name.txt

id.txt files :

```
222222
444444
777777
```

https://filedn.com/lErjiEcIItPyfm4zDdHlyIz/id.txt

I want result like :

```
222222 Bob
444444 July
777777 Guerson
```

I already create shell script to loop id.txt content & cat db_name.txt with grep variable id for each line

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line
do
    cat db_name.txt | grep "$line"
done < "id.txt"
```

But there's no result

Comment: `dos2unix db_name.txt; dos2unix id.txt` and `man dos2unix`

Comment: The bash code is inefficient but works for me.  If you are really not getting the desired output, then try what @Cyrus suggests.

Comment: @John1024 yes, it's typo. My bad

Comment: @Cyrus I'll try it out soon

Comment: @Cyrus It's works, thanks. I think it's because I create the file from Linux under Windows (WSL)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$ grep -Ff id.txt db_name.txt
222222  Bob
444444  July
777777  Guerson
```

How it works:

- `-F` tells grep to treat the patterns as fixed text (no active-regex characters).
- `-f id.txt` tells grep to read the patterns in from file `id.txt`.  Each line in `id.txt` is treated as a pattern, separate and independent of other lines.  Output is produced if any one of the patterns matches.

#### Quick fix for DOS line-endings

`id.dos` is like `id.txt` but has DOS/Windows line endings.  Because of that `grep -Ff id.dos db_name.txt` will produce no output.  As a quick fix, try:

```
$ grep -Ff <(tr -d '\r' <id.dos) db_name.txt
222222  Bob
444444  July
777777  Guerson
```

Comment: Your quick fix is incomplete

Comment: @WalterA Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your shell script and it works for me, so there may be a compatibility issue or other malfunction you are experiencing - but I have a better suggestion, since it looks like you want something like a database table join, you can avoid coding this altogether and just use that command. It's a basement favorite of mine:

```
join id.txt db.txt 
222222 Bob
444444 July
777777 Guerson
```

Note that your expected output is 'July' for 444444, not 'Marry' :-)

Join can be very useful, but you will need to be careful of that your input files are always sorted first by the 'sort' command, but yours is already sorted so I won't go into that.

I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I need to sort both of files first right?

Comment: This works for me: `join <(dos2unix <id.txt | sort) <(dos2unix <db_name.txt | sort)`

Comment: Yes, you need to sort both files. And if you have any leading space or special characters, be sure to use 'sort -b' on each file.  If you ever use join, you should probably just always use sort -b because it is a difficult problem to notice.